# Multiple parallel versions on Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, branch

Suppose I'm developing software for different clients with a common need.
I develop the system with a single line of development, and that is ok. Each client has the software installed on a server, and updates are made by pulling from a bitbucket repository.

Later, one of the clients asks for a custom module for his own needs only. Other clients may also have other custom needs as well.

My problem is: How can I manage the customization, pulling (updating) new versions of the main line of development, and the customs only when they are present?

Answer (score 0):

One option: make the customisation part of the codebase rather than managed through Mercurial. There are lots of good reasons for doing this, including that there's no danger of you forking and ever maintaining separate version of code, or indeed maintaining separate branches of a repository tree. Both of those are pretty dull tasks that could lead to problems, so I'd favour that if I were you. It depends on your language but I would aim for keeping a load of modules in the MainCodeBase with some way for users to configure which are used.

Second option: sub repositories. Make a repo for Customer1 which includes that customer's modules and has a sub-repository of MainCodeBase. Customer1 just needs to recursively pull their repository to get the latest modules and the latest MainCodeBase. Problem here is it starts to get ugly when you want more than one customer to use the same module.